# Correct Results From Python's os.path.join()

Tags: python

After reading the online documentation for the os.path.join() method, the following case seems like it should qualify but apparently it doesn't.  Am I reading that documentation correctly?

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>> os.path.join("/home/user", "/projects/pyproject", "mycode.py")
>>> '/projects/pyproject/mycode.py'
```

After trying different combinations of trailing and leading os.sep on the first and second paths, it seems that the second path to join cannot have its first character start with an os.sep.

```
>>> os.path.join("/home/user", "projects/pyproject", "mycode.py")
>>> '/home/user/projects/pyproject/mycode.py'
```

In the case where path1 and path2 are parts from, say, user input means writing code to parse their input for that leading os.sep.

From the python.org online reference:

> `os.path.join(path1[, path2[, ...]])` Join one or more path components
>   intelligently. If any component is an absolute path, all previous
>   components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there
>   was one)  are thrown away, and joining continues. The return value is
>   the concatenation of `path1`,  and optionally `path2`, etc., with exactly
>   one directory separator (`os.sep`) following each non-empty part except
>   the last. (This means that an empty last part will result in a path
>   that ends with a separator.) Note that on Windows, since there is a
>   current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents
>   a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` (`c:foo`), not
>   `c:\foo`.

Answer (score 8):

> Am I reading that documentation correctly?

Try reading it again, emphasis mine:

> Join one or more path components intelligently. **If any component is an
>   absolute path, all previous components** (on Windows, including the
>   previous drive letter, if there was one)  **are thrown away**, and
>   joining continues. The return value is the concatenation of path1, 
>   and optionally path2, etc., with exactly one directory separator
>   (os.sep) following each non-empty part except the last. (This means
>   that an empty last part will result in a path that ends with a
>   separator.) Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory
>   for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative
>   to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

When it says previous components are "thrown away" means that they are ignored and not included in the final result.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought previous "components" being tossed out would be the os.sep not the entire path.

Comment: That's the behaviour I would also wish it would do, and I just had exact this problem. Reading the docs I understood that it describes what happens. But I still dont understand *why* it is done like that because I can not imagine when this can be useful...

Answer (score 3):

It is just as the documentation says: if any component is absolute, the previous components are thrown away.  If your path begins with `/`, then it is absolute.  If it's not supposed to be absolute, it shouldn't start with `/`.