# Why does os.path.join throw away arguments?

Tags: python, language-design

I'm learning Python and I noticed something strange with one of my scripts.  Doing a little testing I discovered the problem stemmed from this behavior:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('a','b')
'a/b'
>>> os.path.join('a','/b')
'/b'
```

Checking the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path), this is, in fact, the design of the function:

> os.path.**join**(*path1***[**, *path2***[**, ...**]]**)
>
> > Join one or more path components intelligently. If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues. ...

My question isn't [why my script failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11873787/1438), but rather why the function was designed this way.  I mean, on Unix at least, `a//b` is a perfectly acceptable way to designate a path, if not elegant.  Why was the function designed this way?  Is there any way to tell if one or more path elements have been discarded short of testing each path string with `os.path.isabs()`?

---

Out of curiosity, I also checked the case where a path component ends in an `os.sep` character:

```
>>> os.path.join('a/','b')
'a/b'
```

That works as expected.

Comment: An easy, albeit inelegant, way to check for this is to do `filename.lstrip('/')`

Comment: @voithos Make it `filename.lstrip(os.sep)` and it's portable to most major platforms.

Comment: @delnan: you'd have to test on windows, where it is `os.sep + '/'`..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right, assuming the path isn't normalized first. I also just realized that drive letters foul it up again (the path `\foo` exists and refers to the current drive, but it's very rare). Seems like there is no easy way out... then again, I don't recall ever *needing* this.

Comment: @Martijn To make it as generic as possible it should be `os.sep + (os.altsep or "")`.

Comment: @lazyr: Ah, I knew there was a better way. :-)

Comment: Looks to me like a perfectly reasonable way to create a path composition function.

Comment: @jon-ericson Yeah, really strange. May be to prevent considering as a network-path references.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One case where it is useful for `os.path.join('a', '/b')` to return `/b` would be if you ask a user for a filename.

The user can enter either a path relative to the current directory, or a full path, and your program could handle both cases like this:

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
```

---

```
In [54]: os.getcwd()
Out[54]: '/tmp'

In [55]: os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'foo')
Out[55]: '/tmp/foo'

In [56]: os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '/foo/bar')
Out[56]: '/foo/bar'
```

Comment: ... or any other directory really, if there is a sensible default directory for the application.

Comment: And Guido had this in mind from the very [first revision](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5570dbb1ce55/Lib/posixpath.py#11) (where the function started as `cat`, later to be renamed to `join`).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: That's very interesting.  I'd be curious if Guido ever explained the purpose behind the design.  And thank you unutbu for pointing out a meaningful use case.

Answer (score 1):

Think you're writing a utility like `cd` to check the new directory, you would use

```
os.path.join(currdir, newdir)
```

If the user enters `/b` you would except it to throw the first argument. This hold for plenty of thing using current directory.

Comment: but... if I want to write a utiliy like "copy", that copies a file from an absolute path into some other base directory, keeping the parent directories, I do want "/path/to/file" be joined with "/path/to/new/dest/dir"  without anything being dropped ;)