# What's the use case for pythons os.path.join dropping all arguments before when one is an absolute path?

Tags: python

I just stumbled into this part of the python `os.path.join` doc:

"If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component."

I got an unexpected return when trying to calculate a destination path while ftp'ing a file described with an absolute path into a local directory, and naturally I wanted to calculate the directory with join.

```
remote_file = '/path/to/file'
dst_base_dir = '/some/other/dir'
dst_file = os.path.join(dst_base_dir, remote_file)
fetch_file(remote_file, dst_file)
```

This doesn't work, because of the aforementioned way how join() works. It will drop dst_base_dir completely and only return remote_file.

To make it work, I have to check if some path is absolute and if so, prepend a . to get this thing working, like:

```
remote_file = '/path/to/file'

if os.path.isabs(remote_file):
    remote_file = f'.{remote_file}'

dst_base_dir = '/some/other/dir'
dst_file = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dst_base_dir, remote_file))
fetch_file(remote_file, dst_file)
```

In my imagination, the situation when people have a path that starts with a / and still want it to be joined with another path, ignoring the extra / is very common, and having to check each argument for leading slashes and remove them is pretty complicated.

In contrast, I cannot imagine a situation when I have multiple parts of a path and not want to really join them, but having some parts being dropped instead, but I still call join() to join them, wanting join() the way it now is designed to work.

What am I missing? Which are the cases when this behaviour is useful when dealing with real life situations of file pathes that need joining?

Comment: The absolute path takes your `os.getcwd()` path as base. Any extra paths are appended to that base by `os.path.join`.

Comment: Sorry buit I dont understand how this answers my question. Which "absolute path" "takes" cwd as base and where? And why does that make os.path.join() useful the way it works currently, dropping all arguments that appear before one that is an asbolute path?

Comment: Python is assuming that the two paths are in fact complete file paths on their own. `/path/to/file`, as a complete file path, refers *only* to a path starting at the top-level `path` directory. There is no other correct way to interpret it. `path/to/file`, on the other hand, is a relative path which references the current working directory or whichever directory you plan to make it relative to. If you don't intend that the two be valid paths to begin with, then you should treat them as strings, as you do in your second example.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo But Python doesn't need to "interpret" anything. If I call "join" I want nothing more than all arguments being appended, with the OS'es path separator in between. At least I personally cant think of why anybody would give join anything that they do not want to appear in the result.

Comment: Try `print( os.path.join( os.path.abspath('.'), 'myfile.py' ) )`

Comment: @Derek I am asking for an explanation Why os.path.join is designed and useful as it is, in which situation it is useful that somebody calls "join" but really wants parts of the input being just dropped. I don't understand how adding the current working dir via abspath with . helps to answer that. (and I dont want to do anything in the current working directory).

Comment: My example will give you the absolute path to the file. If you try to `os.path.join` another path it will only give you the appended path. `C:\\myfile.py` in my example.

Comment: @Derek but I did not ask for a programming solution, but for reasons why join is designed that way, and in which situation this can be useful, and why my which how it should work is less useful and common. But nevermind, I found another question about that ;) Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: I've taken the long way round to get to my point:) You must join each component separately. Whew!

Comment: Topic is discussed and halfway explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609075/why-does-os-path-join-throw-away-arguments